# C++, OpenGL - Аномалия с текстурой

Tags: c++, opengl

Написал код текстуры на языке OpenGL! Когда использую режим фильтряции текстуры GL_NEAREST то показываеться текстура в пиксельном виде а когда использую режим GL_LINEAR то показваеться текстура в размытом виде. Аномалия происходит с режимом GL_LINEAR, потому что когда я выставляю этот режим то появляються какие-то линий по бокам текстуры!

Картина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стрелки указывают на аномалий!

Часть кода:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, mode, texture->w, texture->h, 
                0, mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture->pixels);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureID);
```

Как исправить такую ощибку?

Видеокарту тоже проверял, но с ней всё в порядке!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это размытие получается из-за свертки текстурных координат. На краю при вычислении усредненного значения используется цвет пикселя с противоположной стороны. Это регулируется атрибутами `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_*`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я это понял, но как исправить эту ощибку?

Comment: @RedBull Добавить по периметру прозрачную полосу.

Comment: Окей, попробую!